# Scrapy: Scrape "next" results on a webpage using scrapy

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'info'
    allowed_domains = ['womenonlyconnected.com']
    start_urls =['http://www.womenonlyconnected.com/socialengine/pageitems/index']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls =  response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield Request(absolute_url , callback = self.parse_page)



    def parse_page(self , response):
        pass
```

here is my code using this code I can scrape only first 24 links only need help in scraping all the links after "view more" on the page
pag url is given bbelow
http://www.womenonlyconnected.com/socialengine/pageitems/index

Answer (score 0):

After little bit of investigation it can be found that you can paginate using this URL:

```
http://www.womenonlyconnected.com/socialengine/pageitems/index?page=N
```

where *N* start with 1 for the first page etc. So I would modify your spider like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'info'
    allowed_domains = ['womenonlyconnected.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.womenonlyconnected.com/socialengine/pageitems/index']
    page_num = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        urls =  response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield Request(absolute_url , callback = self.parse_page)

        if self.page_num < 100:
            self.page_num += 1
            yield Request(start_urls[0] + '?page={}'.format(self.page_num) , callback = self.parse)

    def parse_page(self , response):
        pass
```

The reason that I stop at page 100 is that it's not that easy to determine if there are more results and hence if you should go to the next page. In theory you could check the presence of *View More* element on the page. The problem is that it's always present and it's hidden if there are no more pages with results. But hiding this element happens using JavaScript, so Scrapy always sees it's hidden. To reliably tell if there are more pages, you would have to render the page using e.g. [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: @ Tomáš Linhart, I've checked that site as well. This is the last page `http://www.womenonlyconnected.com/socialengine/pageitems/index?page=47`.

Comment: @Shahin That's not really generic solution as the number of pages probably changes over time when articles are added. Really generic solution involves rendering the page using (headless) browser as suggested with e.g. Splash.